# How to filter array of objects and then return a specific attribute?

Tags: javascript

consider the data :

```
let orders = {
        "data": [
            {
                "email": "a@b.com", "orders": [
                    { "orderName": "something", "price": "43$" },
                    { "orderName": "anotherthing", "price": "4$" }
                ]
            },{
                "email": "c@w.com", "orders": [
                    { "orderName": "fish", "price": "43$" },
                    { "orderName": "parrot", "price": "4$" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
```

I'm trying to filter the orders of the object with some email like:

```
email = 'a@b.com'
x=orders.data.filter(o =>{if (o.email === email) return o.orders});
```

but the whole return value is the whole matching object, with email and orders, and I don't want the whole object , I want only the orders.

Comment: why not just map after filter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: `filter` just checks whether the value returned by the function is truthy or not, it doesn't use it as the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do with `filter` alone, you also need to `map`:

```
orders.data.filter(o => o.email === 'a@b.com').map(o => o.orders)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `find` and then just reference `orders` when needed. Adding `|| {'orders': 'Email not found'};` after will catch if the email isn't found

```js
let orders = {
  "data": [{
    "email": "a@b.com",
    "orders": [{
        "orderName": "something",
        "price": "43$"
      },
      {
        "orderName": "anotherthing",
        "price": "4$"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "email": "c@w.com",
    "orders": [{
        "orderName": "fish",
        "price": "43$"
      },
      {
        "orderName": "parrot",
        "price": "4$"
      }
    ]
  }]
};

email = 'a@b.com'
x = orders.data.find(o => {
  return o.email === email
}) || {
  'orders': 'Email not found'
};
console.log(x.orders);
email = 'x@y.com'
x = orders.data.find(o => {
  return o.email === email
}) || {
  'orders': 'Email not found'
};
console.log(x.orders);
```

Comment: if they are in the same object (since they have the same email) then orders will contain all the orders. If there are separate objects with the same email this won't work in getting them all

Comment: Ah perhaps. If that's the case, you may want to consider handling the case in which the email isn't found. Currently I believe your code will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with `.filter` as the method will only return a subsection if the array, while you want to also transform it.

You can chain [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to produce the result:

```js
let orders = { "data": [{ "email": "a@b.com", "orders": [{ "orderName": "something", "price": "43$" }, { "orderName": "anotherthing", "price": "4$" } ] }, { "email": "c@w.com", "orders": [{ "orderName": "fish", "price": "43$" }, { "orderName": "parrot", "price": "4$" } ] }]};

email = 'a@b.com';
x = orders.data
  .filter(o => o.email === email)
  .map(o => o.orders);
  
console.log(x);
```

If you expect a single element here, you can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead:

```js
let orders = { "data": [{ "email": "a@b.com", "orders": [{ "orderName": "something", "price": "43$" }, { "orderName": "anotherthing", "price": "4$" } ] }, { "email": "c@w.com", "orders": [{ "orderName": "fish", "price": "43$" }, { "orderName": "parrot", "price": "4$" } ] }]};

email = 'a@b.com';
x = orders.data
  .find(o => o.email === email)
  .orders;
  
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let orders = {
        "data": [
            {
                "email": "a@b.com", "orders": [
                    { "orderName": "something", "price": "43$" },
                    { "orderName": "anotherthing", "price": "4$" }
                ]
            },{
                "email": "c@w.com", "orders": [
                    { "orderName": "fish", "price": "43$" },
                    { "orderName": "parrot", "price": "4$" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
    
const filteredOrders = orders.data.map((o) => o.email === 'a@b.com' ? o.orders : null).filter(o => o);

console.log(filteredOrders)
```

You can map first too and filter after that the valid results.